# ¿Cómo está actuando la herencia en cascada dentro de esta lista?

Tags: html, css

En el siguiente **código** trato de experimentar con las animaciones.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ejercicio_2</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimun-scale=1" />

<style type="text/css">
    
    .slider{
        width: 22.25%;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    /*Cuando llega a la última imagen, regresa hacia la primera directamente*/
    .slider #ul_1{
        width: 400%;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        animation: cambio_1 20s infinite;
    }
    
    /*Cuando llega a la última imagen, regresa a la primera pasando antes por el resto*/
    .slider #ul_2{
        width: 400%;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        animation: cambio_2 20s infinite alternate;
    }
    
    .slider ul li{
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    .slider ul li img{
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    @keyframes cambio_1{
        0% {margin-left: 0;}
        20% {margin-left: 0;}
        
        25% {margin-left: -100%;}
        45% {margin-left: -100%;}
        
        50% {margin-left: -200%;}
        65% {margin-left: -200%;}
        
        70% {margin-left: -300%;}
        95% {margin-left: -300%;}
    }
    
    @keyframes cambio_2{
        0% {margin-left: 0;}
        20% {margin-left: 0;}
        
        25% {margin-left: -100%;}
        45% {margin-left: -100%;}
        
        50% {margin-left: -200%;}
        70% {margin-left: -200%;}
        
        75% {margin-left: -300%;}
        100% {margin-left: -300%;}
    }
    
</style>    
    
    
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="slider">
        
        <ul id="ul_1">
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_1.jpg" alt="paisaje_1"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_2.jpg" alt="paisaje_2"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_3.jpg" alt="paisaje_3"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_4.jpg" alt="paisaje_4"></li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul id="ul_2">
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_1.jpg" alt="paisaje_1"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_2.jpg" alt="paisaje_2"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_3.jpg" alt="paisaje_3"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_4.jpg" alt="paisaje_4"></li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Sin embargo, me ha surgido una **duda en cuanto al ancho heredado en cascada**. Yo entiendo lo siguiente:

(1) El *slider* tendrá el 22.25% del ancho que tenga el *body*.

(2) Cada *ul* tendrá un ancho cuatro veces mayor que el *slider*, pues hay cuatro imágenes y queremos que cada imagen ocupe el 100% del *slider* cuando aparezca.

**(3) Aquí mi duda**. Por lo que veo experimentalmente, los elementos *li* deben tener un ancho del 100% para que todos los elementos de la lista queden equitativamente repartidos. Ahora bien, acorde con la herencia en cascada y la lógica de las medidas relativas, **¿no debería ocupar, según la instrucción de anchura definida, cada *li* todo el ancho de la lista a la que pertenece?** De esta manera, quedaría cada elemento *li* como cuatro veces el slider.

(4) Ajustamos el ancho de la imagen a la del *li* para que no queden huecos internos en los laterales.

Si unimos el punto 3 con el punto 4, es evidente que debería ocupar cada imagen un ancho cuatro veces mayor al *slider*. Sin embargo, el ajuste parece perfecto y las animaciones ocurren sin problemas.

¿Cómo está actuando entonces la cascada con la anchura de los *li*? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La duda principal:

> Por lo que veo experimentalmente, los elementos li deben tener un ancho del 100% para que todos los elementos de la lista queden equitativamente repartidos. Ahora bien, acorde con la herencia en cascada y la lógica de las medidas relativas, ¿no debería ocupar, según la instrucción de anchura definida, cada li todo el ancho de la lista a la que pertenece? De esta manera, quedaría cada elemento li como cuatro veces el slider.

Todo esto **es correcto con una propiedad `display` diferente de `flex`** para el contenedor y la explicación es muy sencilla:

- La suma del ancho de todos supera el 100% y el contenedor flex ajustará para que todos quepan en el contenedor, con la misma medida proporcional (100% / cantidad de elementos). Agrega (o elimina) un elemento para comprobarlo.
- La suma del ancho de todos es menor que el 100%, entonces se ajustarán para ocupar solo ese espacio en el contenedor. Cambia el ancho de los elementos a un número donde la suma no llegue a 100 para comprobarlo.

```css
.slider{
        width: 22.25%;
        margin: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    /*Cuando llega a la última imagen, regresa hacia la primera directamente*/
    .slider #ul_1{
        width: 400%;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        animation: cambio_1 20s infinite;
    }
    
    /*Cuando llega a la última imagen, regresa a la primera pasando antes por el resto*/
    .slider #ul_2{
        width: 400%;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        animation: cambio_2 20s infinite alternate;
    }
    
    .slider ul li{
        /* La suma de elementos es mayor a 100% */
        width: 100%;
        list-style: none;
        background: #ccc;
        border: 1px red solid;
    }

    #ul_2 li{
        /* La suma de elementos no llega al 100% */
        width: 15%;
        list-style: none;
        background: #ccc;
        border: 1px red solid;
    }


    .slider ul li img{
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    @keyframes cambio_1{
        0% {margin-left: 0;}
        20% {margin-left: 0;}
        
        25% {margin-left: -100%;}
        45% {margin-left: -100%;}
        
        50% {margin-left: -200%;}
        65% {margin-left: -200%;}
        
        70% {margin-left: -300%;}
        95% {margin-left: -300%;}
    }
    
    @keyframes cambio_2{
        0% {margin-left: 0;}
        20% {margin-left: 0;}
        
        25% {margin-left: -100%;}
        45% {margin-left: -100%;}
        
        50% {margin-left: -200%;}
        70% {margin-left: -200%;}
        
        75% {margin-left: -300%;}
        100% {margin-left: -300%;}
    }
```

```html
<div class="slider">
        
        <ul id="ul_1">
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_1.jpg" alt="paisaje_1"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_2.jpg" alt="paisaje_2"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_3.jpg" alt="paisaje_3"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_4.jpg" alt="paisaje_4"></li>
            <!-- Elemento extra para ver que solo se ocupa el 100% -->
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_5.jpg" alt="paisaje_5"></li>
        </ul>
        
        <ul id="ul_2">
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_1.jpg" alt="paisaje_1"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_2.jpg" alt="paisaje_2"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_3.jpg" alt="paisaje_3"></li>
            <li><img src="imagenes/paisaje_4.jpg" alt="paisaje_4"></li>
        </ul>
        
    </div>
```

En este ejemplo puedes ver que el primer slider tiene 5 elementos y entre todos ocupan solo la anchura disponible; el segundo no llega a ocuparla porque las medidas entre todos son menores de 100%.

Para ser más específicos, de acuerdo a tu duda final:

> ¿Cómo está actuando entonces la cascada con la anchura de los li?

La respuesta se obtiene del manual de [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

> La propiedad CSS flex indica la **capacidad de un elemento flexible para alterar sus dimensiones y llenar el espacio disponible**. Los elementos flexibles pueden ser estirados para utilizar el espacio disponible proporcional a su factor de crecimiento flexible o su factor de contracción flexible para evitar desbordamiento.

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices y lo veo experimentalmente. Ahora bien, su respuesta se contradice con la información que se encuentra en el siguiente enlace: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox. Aquí podrá leer: "Si hay más ítems de los que caben en el contenedor, estos no pasarán más abajo si no que sobrepasarán el margen.". Justo entonces tiene un entorno de prueba donde puede añadir dentro del flexbox tantos ítems como desee, que estos no se ajustan equitativamente al contenedor, sino que lo sobrepasan. ¿Está mal entonces esta fuente?

Comment: @SergioDuránVega, no hay contradicción, lee a partir de [Propiedades aplicadas a los elementos flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#propiedades_aplicadas_a_los_%C3%ADtems_flex) y cada una de las propiedades para saber cómo se modifica el comportamiento para ocupar solo el espacio disponible o se desborda sin aplicar `width` a los elementos internos, sino `flex-basis`, `flex-grow` o `flex-shrink`.

Comment: creo que de momento es una propiedad que escapa a mi comprensión. No hago más que leer la documentación y no me parece muy esclarecedora. Seguiré haciendo ejercicios y ya lo iré entendiendo a medida que me encuentre con más casos. Gracias por su ayuda.